# Django Channels send message from python websocket-client module

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels, channel

I have a Django Channels server which I intend to use as a websocket server. I am trying to send message to websocket with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client

I can pass the handshake phase and can see connect log in the terminal. However, when I send message to server, I can not see in consumers.py ws_message function that prints message. Also, I can not see the message in frontend. How can I send message to websocket ?

consumers.py

```
from channels import Group
from game.models import Game


def ws_add(message, order_id):
    game = Game.objects.get(order__id=order_id)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    Group("game" + str(game.id)).add(message.reply_channel)

def ws_message(message, order_id):
    print message
    game = Game.objects.get(order__id=order_id)    
    Group("game" + str(game.id)).send({
        "text": message['text'],
    })

def ws_disconnect(message, order_id):
    game = Game.objects.get(order__id=order_id)    
    Group("game" + str(game.id)).discard(message.reply_channel)
```

send.py

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("ws://localhost:8000/game/1/stream")
print("Sending 'Hello, World'...")
ws.send("Hello, World")
print("Sent")
ws.close()
```

routing.py

```
from channels.routing import route
from game.consumers import ws_add, ws_message, ws_disconnect

channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.connect", ws_add, path="^/game/(?P<order_id>\d+)/stream/$"),
    route("websocket.receive", ws_message, path="^/game/(?P<order_id>\d+)/stream/$"),
    route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect, path="^/game/(?P<order_id>\d+)/stream/$"),
]
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code. At least show us the `consumers`, the `routing` on server side and the client connection.

Comment: I include consumers, routing and sample send @hoefling

Comment: Also, I think django requires urls to end with a slash - it should probably be `ws = create_connection("ws://localhost:8000/game/1/stream/")`

Comment: My comments about signatures were incorrect and there's nothing wrong with that, my apologies.

Comment: No problem @hoefling

Comment: adding slash solved the issue. Thanks for your helping @hoefling :)